# Is it possible to bypass trait method in PHP?

Tags: php, traits

I've got main base class:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public function process()
    {
        echo 'Base::process()';
    }
}
```

and trait:

```
trait ProtectionTrait
{
    public function process()
    {
        echo 'ProtectionTrait::process()';
    }
}
```

Then I create class extending BaseClass and using ProtectionTrait with changing its `process()` method name to other:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    use ProtectionTrait {
        process as omittedProcess;
    }
}
```

I'd like to bypass ProtectionTrait::process() method by changing its name (like above), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$obj = new ChildClass();
$obj->process();
// outputs 'ProtectionTrait::process()'
```

It is possible to bypass selected method from the trait, so the method of parent class will be invoked? I know I can put the `process()` method in ChildClass and there invoke `parent::process()` there manually, but is it possible to do it the other way?

Comment: Nope, as trait has a precedence over inherited methods.

Comment: You would need to *re-declare* the method on the child class, and directly call the parent method with: `parent::process();`. The `as` operator in your example only creates an alias usable to resolve a naming conflict. It does not rename the method.